# In laravel Form::text() what the second paramater null actually refers to

Tags: laravel

I am beginner user of a laravel framework and learning by watching a tutorials but i get stucked the with a question that what the second paramater null in Form::text() actually refers

```
  {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: It sets the value of text field using second argument [Creating a Text Input Field](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/155/creating-a-text-input-field)

Comment: Thanks for your help ! i got it

Comment: i don't get the question

Comment: {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}  what does null refers in this code ...If you are working with a laravel framework then you must get it !